# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)

Tags: jss, experience-editor, nextjs

I followed the steps on https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/client-frameworks/getting-started/app-deployment to get my local starter app connected to my local sitecore install.

In the nextjs app it works fine, but in the experience editor I was getting a strange error:
"A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)"

While debugging the error in nextjs I saw a strange value in the itemPath:
[image]
This all happens in this file: `node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss-nextjs\dist\cjs\middleware\editing-render-middleware.js`

As a hack I replaced the "https://https" in the return:

[image]

Now it works fine in the exp editor, but I assume I must have something not configured right.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to sitecore stack exchange. How is your hostname configured in the config of the app? Do you have one set or have it as the default one?

Comment: why is it even 2 https in your request? it should be 1

Comment: @CristiVulturar 
Yes, this is in my configuration:
<app name="jss-nextjs-app"
            sitecorePath="/sitecore/content/jss-nextjs-app"
            graphQLEndpoint="/sitecore/api/graph/edge"
            inherits="defaults"
            serverSideRenderingEngine="http"
      
          serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl="http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render"
            serverSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl="http://localhost:3000/"
        />

In my .env file the reference to sitecore is made with this line I believe:
SITECORE_API_HOST=https://jsssandbox.sc

Comment: @MaheshRaghupathi I know it should be one, that's why I got the temporarily hack in place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the configuration of the hostname:

https://jsssandbox.sc should've been jsssandbox.sc
It works like a charm now!